# SENTRY ErrorMsg - raven@2.6.3 alert: failed to send exception to sentry: Connection timed out on request to sentry.io. How to solve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sentry

Trying to send a log from a Lambda function from AWS to Sentry.io.
This is the log I get from `CoudWatch`:

```
raven@2.6.3 alert: failed to send exception to sentry: Connection timed out on request to sentry.io

raven@2.6.3 alert: failed to send exception to sentry: socket hang up
```

Any Idea how to fix it? No clues about it into [serverless plugin](https://github.com/arabold/serverless-sentry-plugin).

Comment: Maybe you have configured a VPC for the Lambda and therefore can’t reach the server?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am going to find a way to allow Sentry to pass trough the vpc.